# Creating TCP Client Connection in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7.5

I developed a simple MVC page that creates a TCP client connection to another server to exchange information. It is working fine while I'm in debug mode with using local IIS web server. However, when I publish it to my remote server, I'm having an error while connecting through TCP client. The error is just a simple page "Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request.".

I think that it is just because of the configuration settings of my IIS 7.5. How can I give permission to my web site to connect through TCP client to another server?

Comment: Hello, can you publish your code

Comment: Enable remote debugging and post your stack race. Give us a clue. Firewall might be an issues.

Comment: I have to ask the obvious: can your "remote server" resolve the name of the machine you're attempting to reach?

Answer (score 0):

From the information you provided in your question it is very difficult to say what the problem might be. Make sure that there is no firewall blocking the connection between your web server and the remote server. It is unlikely that this has to do with IIS. Contact your network administrator to ensure that the remote server is reachable from the web server.